# SpeechRecognitionEngine.AudioLevel does not change

Tags: c#, audio, voice-recognition

I've been working with the Kinect and Voice Recognition, and I'm noticing that I can't get the `AudioLevel` member to change from my `SpeechRecognitionEngine` object.

I am successful in getting the commands to be recognized, so I know that the kinect is presenting my application with sound. I've tried subscribing to the `AudioLevelUpdated` event and reading the `AudioLevel` directly, but the event doesn't fire and the `AudioLevel` is always 0.

Is there anything special I need to do activate the `AudioLevel`?

Comment: have you run the kinect calibration for the user you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember having the same problem in the past. In my search for a solution I found that it could have several reasons but I haven't really been able (have not had the time) to pinpoint the problem for my case yet. I will still list some reasons I have found.

- It is not using SAPI 5.3 and therefore will always return zero because SAPI 5.1 doesn't support this.
- It has been reported in several forums that it may be a .NET v4 runtime problem.
- The AudioLevel is based on `AudioStatus.dwAudioLevel` which may return 0 for a reason.

A workaround which has been suggested on MSDN(by IanPeters) and worked ok for me was to extract the sample audio from the Recognized audio, use `RecognizedAudio.WriteToWaveStream()` and then take the average of the absolute value of the audio. This will give you an estimate and could be sufficient for your situation.

The original post of IanPeters is located on msdn ([SpeechRecognitionEngine.AudioLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.audiolevel.aspx))

Comment: this is basically what I've done (manually finding the audio level).  Thanks for sharing your findings!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and i solve it by

```
// Configure input to the speech recognizer.
recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
```

then put this line to handle the event

```
// Add an event handler for the AudioLevelUpdated event.
recognizer.AudioLevelUpdated += new EventHandler<AudioLevelUpdatedEventArgs>(recognizer_AudioLevelUpdated);
```

then to print the current audio level implement the recognizer_AudioLevelUpdated method

```
void recognizer_AudioLevelUpdated(object sender, AudioLevelUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The audio level is now: {0}.", e.AudioLevel);
}
```

then the audio level values will be between 1 ... 100.